# AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'evaluate'

Tags: python, keras, error-handling

I built a neural network to solve a multi class classification problem. When I now try to evaluate the model I got the following error:

```
results = estimator.evaluate(X_val, y_val, batch_size=8)

AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'evaluate'
```

What should I modify regarding my code?

Comment: I get: `AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'model_'`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try:

`results = estimator.score(X_val, y_val)`

This is because the `KerasClassifier` is supposed to mimic the behavior of `scikit-learn` and its classifiers, I think